# It is possible to pass an empty string literal to a user-defined raw literal operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, user-defined-literals

Consider the following simple user-defined raw literal operator:

```
#include <string>

std::string operator""_s(const char* s) {
  return s;
}
```

which gives us another easier way to generate `std::string`s with only integer characters:

```
auto s1 = 012345_s; // s1 is "0123456"s
auto s2 = 0_s;      // s2 is "0"s
```

But is it possible to generate **empty** string using this raw literal operator?

```
auto s3 = ???_s;    // s3 is ""s
```

Comment: `auto s3 = operator""_s("");` :-)

Comment: To be honest, I like this answer. This more like a trick since we can call `operator""_s("hello")`.

Answer (score 4):

The single-argument form `T operator""_s(const char* s)` is just a fallback case for integers and floating-point types.
The proper way to handle a user-defined string literal  is via `T operator""_s(const CharT* s, size_t sz)`.

```
#include <string>

std::string operator""_s(const char* s) {
  return s;
}

std::string operator""_s(const char* s, size_t sz) {
  return {s,sz};
}

int main()
{
    auto s1 = 012345_s;
    auto s2 = 0_s;  
    auto s3 = ""_s;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qYM1WaKrh

Comment: But now, `"abc"_s` is also valid. Not sure of OP intents.

Comment: OP used invalid form of user defined literal and this answer shows it. (more or less). `operator""_s(const char* s)` suppose to be used when you need provide custom interpretation of literal whcih could be integer or float. For example provide base 11 numbers.

Comment: What is the point for the second overload since STL already provides `operator""s`.  I think your answer is: "it not possible to generate empty string **only** using the raw literal operator."

Comment: The fact that "" is an empty string doesn't change the fact it's a string literal, so you still need the two-argument form. If you want "" to be the only valid string (as @Jarod42 suggests) and be warned at compile-time, I'm afraid I don't know how to do that without making `s3` itself constexpr...